# ArgoCD add repository credential template (repocreds add) fails

Tags: templates, repository, openshift, credentials, argocd

We have succesfully added several BitBucket private repository to ArcoCD, using the URL and access token. We can also see them both on the UI and via CLI. (argocd repo list)

[ArgoCD repo list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqzf0.png)

I would be good to centralize the credentials of them, so **wanted to introduce the credential template**, but when doing it:

- From the UI, the template credential saving seems to be succesfull. (No error appears and also the Repo list screen show the added template on the screen until I refresh) **After refresh it disappears, so most probably it is not saved on server side at all.**
- From the cli, saving also seems to be succesfull, but **the list does not retrieve anything.**

```
argocd repocreds add https://bitbucket.../scm --username [user] --password [token]
Repository credentials for 'https://bitbucket.xxx.yy/scm' added

argocd repocreds list
URL PATTERN  USERNAME  SSH_CREDS  TLS_CREDS
```

ArgoCD runs in OpenShft, installed via the ArgoCd Operator. Current ArgoCD version is 2.0.0
As I see, the repos and credential templates are stored in a ConfigMap, called argocd-cm.
If I add repos, they appear under repositories key:
[OpenShift, argocd-cm, repositories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jrHi.png)

If I add credential templates, nothing appears under repository.credentials key:
[OpenShift, argocd-cm, repository.credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImGzx.png)

**As a summary I am unable to save repository credentials (Credential templates) nor from the UI neither from CLI in ArgoCd 2.0.0 running in OpenShift.**

Has anybody faced with teh same issue? Any idea or workaround for the issue?
I thought to fill in the repository.credentials key manually, but I don't have a sample for that.